# Execution of oracle procedure multiple times in powerbuilder 12.0

Tags: oracle, powerbuilder

I wrote a stored procedure in oracle to check weather given input file name exists in defined path. It is working fine. When i call this procedure in power-builder 12.0 i tested like this. First time i entered wrong file name it is works fine. Then i entered correct file name it is saying that **Procedure has already been executed**. How can i re-execute this procedure again. MY code to declare the procedure in package is

```
 DECLARE PROC_FILE_EXISTS PROCEDURE FOR 

HICSWIN_ORACLE.PACK_UPDATE_TSHML_HICSWIN20.PROC_CHECK_FILES_RELEVANCE  
(  
         FILE_NAME => :as_file_name  
)  ;


EXECUTE PROC_FILE_EXISTS;

IF SQLCA.SqlCode < 0 THEN
    MessageBox('eroor',SQLCA.SQLErrText)
    MessageBox('Connection failed','An error occured while connecting to database, please contact your administrartor')
    RETURN 0
end if
```

FYI i am using windows 7 with oracle 11g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to close the procedure call (in a way similar to a cursor use : `Declare` / `Open` / `Fetch` / `Close`):

```
close PROC_FILE_EXISTS;
```

Answer (score 1):

Call it from a datastore.  Create a new dw with a stored procedure source, and the string retrieval argument.  PB includes all the appropriate cursor syntax automatically.  Calling Oracle SPs may be more complex - I believe you have to return a ref cursor to call one from a dw...